# How convert list of numbers to list of points on x-axis?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of real numbers, say:

```
  vec = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 6]
(* {2, 4, 7, 10, 13, 6} *)
```

I want to convert each of these numbers to the corresponding point on the *x*-axis, that is, to obtain:

```
  {{2, 0}, {4, 0}, {7, 0}, {10, 0}, {13, 0}, {6, 0}}
```

The purpose of doing this is to include these points, among other graphics objects, in the plot of a function.

Here are some ways to do it:

```
  Partition[Riffle[vec, 0], 2]
  (Append[#, 0] &) /@ Partition[vec, 1]
  PadRight[#, 2] & /@ Partition[vec, 1]
  vec /. x_?NumericQ -> {x, 0}
```

What is an especially simple way to do this that will be readily understandable by somebody relatively new to *Mathematica* -- especially somebody who may still be uncomfortable with employing pure functions, functional approaches, and pattern-matching?

Comment: Related: [(7996)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121), [(45980)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45980/121)

Comment: I see two reopen votes on this question yet the Accepted answer shows exactly the same methods as the answers in the original.  The question itself is also identical except for an updated emphasis on a "simple way" but since the "simple way" is *already* shown in the original this does not differentiate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
vec = {2, 4, 7, 10, 13, 6};

{#, 0} & /@ vec
```

> {{2, 0}, {4, 0}, {7, 0}, {10, 0}, {13, 0}, {6, 0}}

```
Thread[{vec, 0}]
```

> {{2, 0}, {4, 0}, {7, 0}, {10, 0}, {13, 0}, {6, 0}}

Comment: I especially like `Thread[{vec,0}]` because it's not only short, but also avoids use of pure functions.

Comment: Very much out-of-the-box approach with `Thread` +1

Comment: +1. `Thread` certainly is a beautiful solution. Nevertheless the performance advantage of a pure function seems hard to beat?

Comment: @gwr I doubt that `Thread` will be slower. As an in-built function, it should be quite efficient (but you are very welcome to benchmark).

Comment: I did with 1 Mio random numbers in the vector and the pure function was faster by around 25 % though in absolute duration that did maybe not matter that much (around .13 secs for my machine for the Thread-sokution).

Answer (score 13):

There's no need to convert points on the real line to points in the Cartesian plane.

Simply use `NumberLinePlot` with `Spacings-> 0`

```
NumberLinePlot[{2, 4, 7, 10, 13, 6}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image: points]

Comment: I'm afraid using `NumberLinePlot` doesn't solve the problem, as the points on the *x*-axis I want to form are going to go into the `Epilog` of a `Plot` expression. And it's not obvious how to combine a `NumberLinePlot` with a `Plot` by means of `Show`, even though both have head `Graphics`.

Comment: You may easily combine `Plot`  and `NumberLinePlot`. For example, `Show[{
  Plot[2 Sin[x] + x, {x, 0, 15}],
  NumberLinePlot[{2, 4, 7, 10, 13, 6}, Spacings -> 0]}]`

Comment: you're right, I'm wrong. My test with `Show` had a typo!

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
 SeedRandom[1]; {#, 0} & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 6]
```

> ```
> {{6, 0}, {1, 0}, {8, 0}, {1, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}}
> ```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't accept two answers: your use of `{#,0}&/@` came first. But @Bob Hanlon's answer included also the so-nice use of `Thread`.

Answer (score 5):

If the starting point is ***vec*** one approach would be

```
Transpose[{vec, ConstantArray[0, Length[vec]]}]
```

Comment: Even though this approach is hardly the tersest, it is very easy to understand, even by a beginner: no pure functions, no use of `Map`, no other functional construct such as `Thread`. (Having grown up programming in APL, this way should have occurred to me.)

Answer (score 5):

There are of course more compact solutions but I like the readability of `Function` avoiding the slot notations:

```
f = Function[ x, {x, 0}, Listable ];

f @ { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}}

A thing to note may be that using `g` instead of `f`

```
g = {#, 0}& /@ #&
```

eventually is much faster and also beats many other solutions.

Comment: Actually, efficiency was not among my concerns; brevity and, especially, transparency to those relatively new to *Mathematica* were. (Perhaps I should have said that.)

Comment: That is why I sometimes go for the named function as it is so close to mathematics. While beatifully compact I do find other solutions quite unfortunate with regard to transparency and ease of understanding.